# unable to boot, gets to initramfs and can't go further

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption, home-directory, initramfs

I run a Virtual Machine Ubuntu 16.04 on VMWARE and I believe that the File System is corrupt since when I boot the machine it gets to a `initramfs` (see **2**).

The entire disk is encrypted, so when the OS boots, I get the usual passphrase prompt, and this part works fine (see **1**). I also have the home folder encrypted.

So since I can unlock the partition I tried to boot on a Live USB, unlocked the partition  (see **3**), accessed the home folder to copy the files I need, but got stuck at the user folder. It told me this (see **4**):

> You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "Linux".

So I'm looking for solutions to either access my home folder or fix the file system to be able to access the OS again. I have added screenshots:

1. [image: 1]
2. [image: 2]
3. [image: 3]
4. [image: 4]

Answer (score -1):

Type the `exit` command and find out which drive is your `/` root drive. Then run following commands:

```bsh
fsck -y /dev/sda1            # (in your case sda1 will be something else)
reboot
```

Comment: Nope, I tried it already and I just gave it an other shot... and still the smae issue...